# Spring Boot App in IntelliJ - Unimplemented Bytecode

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

On several Spring Boot apps I am creating, I get an error that causes the app to crash consistently.  I am using IntelliJ 2020.1. Coretto (OpenJDK 11).  On Mac OSX 10.15 (Catalina).  Here is the error :

```
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: unimplemented bytecode ================
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (methodData.cpp:1079), pid=17022, tid=36099
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.7+10) (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/ayunas/spring/spring-cloud/eurekaserver/hs_err_pid17022.log

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Here is the error log that was generated :

https://www.evernote.com/l/AQ1M7UZRefpERaAqZtx7PUOOQJBdqPj6uBU

Any support is very much appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: You get this on several apps, and you can consistently reproduce it? Then you might want to file a bug report.